# WSO2 ESB Store and Forward Processor not obeying endpoint message format

Tags: wso2-esb

We have been testing the message processors and queues on wso2 esb. We have been using the sampling processor quite successfully to just log data to a DB. This POX end to end. The sampling processor correctly dequeues a message and sends it to the endpoint. The endpoint is defined as POX and non-chunked, and all this works well.

We decided to try the store and forward processor as we wanted to test out the guaranteed delivery mechanism. So we created a new processor and defined it as store and forward. In the main sequence that stores the message, we added the target.endpoint property before storing the message. The property was set to the same endpoint that was being used in the sampling scenario.

However - what have found is that in this mode, the message transformation does not happen correctly. The content type is set to text/html and the output is chunked. This causes our service to return a 415 error.

We have tried adding messageType, contentType etc to multiple place, to the axis http sender transport, etc, but it seems to make no difference at all.

Any guidance on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Define the following property in the sequence before sending to the endpoint

```
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: That is the problem - we can't do this. We have added this to the endpoint already. The way the store and forward works, it does not call any of our sequences, so we cannot add this. The processor directly calls the endpoint. But, unlike other areas of the esb which obey the settings in the endpoint, this processor seems to completely ignore the properties of the endpoint. We have set pox and no chunking, but both of these are being ignored.

Comment: Can you provide your full synapse configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The JS code below simply inserts the messageID into the return payload to the caller. Using this with a sampling processor and sequence that simply sends to the same endpoint works fine.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <registry provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.WSO2Registry">
            <parameter name="cachableDuration">15000</parameter>
        </registry>

        <endpoint name="test_e">
            <address uri="http://192.168.45.168:8080/cgi-bin/esbcgi.pl" format="pox"/>
            <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
        </endpoint>

        <sequence name="fault" trace="enable">
            <log level="full">
                <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default 'fault' sequence"/>
                <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
                <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
            </log>
            <drop/>
        </sequence>

        <sequence name="main" onError="fault" trace="enable">
            <in>
                <log level="full"/>
                <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
                <property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
                <script language="js">
                var message = mc.getMessageID(); 
                var messageId = message.substring(9,45); 
                var payload = mc.getPayloadXML().*; 
                mc.setPayloadXML(                                                                                                                                                               
                &lt;payload&gt;                                                                                                                                                          &lt;messageId&gt;{messageId}&lt;/messageId&gt;{payload}                                                                                                                  
                &lt;/payload&gt;);
                </script>

                <switch xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" source="get-property('To')">

                    <case regex=".*/TEST/.*">
                        <property name="target.endpoint" value="test_e" scope="default"/>
                        <store messageStore="TEST"/>
                    </case>
                    <default/>
                </switch>

                <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="false"/>
                <script language="js">var serviceMessageId = mc.getMessageID();
                mc.setPayloadXML(                                                                                                                                                        
                   &lt;tag xmlns="http://tagcmd.com"&gt;        
                   &lt;messageId&gt;{serviceMessageId}&lt;/messageId&gt;                                                                                                                 &lt;/tag&gt;);
                </script>

                <send>
                    <endpoint key="MessageService"/>
                </send>
            </in>

            <out>
                <script language="js">
                var messagePayload= mc.getPayloadXML().*.*;         
                mc.setPayloadXML(                                                                                                                                                        
                &lt;eventResponse&gt;                                                                                                                                                    &lt;messageId&gt;{messagePayload}&lt;/messageId&gt;                                                                                                                      &lt;/eventResponse&gt;);
                </script>
                <send/>
            </out>

            <description>The main sequence for the message mediation</description>
        </sequence>


        <messageStore class="org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore" name="TEST">
            <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.qpid.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
            <parameter name="store.jms.destination">APP8</parameter>
        </messageStore>


        <messageProcessor class="org.apache.synapse.message.processors.forward.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor" name="test_p2" messageStore="TEST">
            <parameter name="max.deliver.attempts">1</parameter>
        </messageProcessor>

    </definitions>
```